# transform pandas dataframe index to be based on dataframe values, while changing values to booleans

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two datasets of company names with naming variations between the two (ex: Merck & Co. vs Merck & Co vs Merck & Co., Inc.)

I am trying to create a "map" where all the unique variants of "Merck" match to "Merck & Co."

My current approach is to create a dictionary, convert to a dataframe, and ideally perform this transformation described below:

```
    Company 1        Company 2         Company 3
0   Co1 variant 0    Co1 variant 0     Co3 variant 0
1   Co1 variant 1    Co2 variant 1     
2   Co1 variant 2
```

Should become:

```
                  Company 1       Company 2         Company 3
Co1 variant 0     True            True              False
Co1 variant 1     True            False             False
Co1 variant 2     True            False             False
Co2 variant 0     False           True              False
Co2 variant 1     False           True              False
Co3 variant 0     False           True              True
```

From here if each row only has 1 `True` value in the row, I would match this naming variant to the column header, otherwise I would match it to itself; allowing the final data set to look like

```
    Variants        Matched Name
0   Co1 variant 0   Co1 variant 0
1   Co1 variant 1   Company 1
2   Co1 variant 2   Company 1
3   Co2 variant 1   Company 2
4   Co3 variant 0   Company 3
```

Thank you in advance for any input, I'm also happy to clarify further if the question is not clear enough.

Comment: Do you want both of the results, or just the last one?

Comment: The last one provides the most value to me. If there is another approach to get to the final result I am also open to such recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stack the original data frame and then group by the row id number and the variants, check how many rows you have for each group, if there are only one row, select the *company* otherwise select the *variants* itself:

```
(df.stack().rename("Variants").rename_axis(("RowId", "Company")).reset_index()
 .groupby(["RowId", "Variants"])
 .apply(lambda g: g.Company.iloc[0] if g.Company.size == 1 else g.Variants.iloc[0])
 .rename("Matched Names").reset_index().drop("RowId", axis = 1))
```

[image]